# X11 Forwarding over USB to TTL Cable?

Tags: usb, terminal

I have USB Console Cable and I used this tutorial [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/connect-the-lead) and I know I can use the terminal, but is there a way I could use the GUI, eg. X-11 Forwarding?

I also know about the ability to connect the raspberry pi directly to the computer over an ethernet cord (I tried a tutorial on that and I couldn't get it to work quite right, I'm going to try again) and I know I can do it (X-11 Forwarding) that way.

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have elaborated more on my question. I simply want to know if it's possible to use the GUI over the USB Console Cable. I have used the terminal and it works great, but I was wondering if using the GUI was possible over this cable, perhaps by a separate program than Screen (what the tutorial has me use to access the terminal over the USB Console Cable).

I haven't really tried much, mostly following tutorials and reading books, as I am relatively new to Linux and I haven't done a whole lot with low-level devices, but I want to. The Raspberry Pi is the way I'm planning to do this because I can experiment with a lot of things, without risking my files.

Anyway, if there is any way to get a GUI over the Console Cable, that is what I would like to try. I'll keep searching around, I just thought I would ask here in case someone with more experience in Linux/RPi had done something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: what is the question? please elaborate on what you want to achieve, what have you already tried, and in what spectacular way you failed in your attempts to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question, though I can't really add anything, as I haven't tried anything yet. I didn't want to risk bricking my Pi by accident doing something that isn't safe, so I thought I'd ask here, to see if anyone with more experience in Linux/RPi had done something similar or knew of a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Xorg has an extension called LBX which is a low bandwidth version of X11 for serial communication introduced in X11R6.3 and removed post R7. The Linux Document project has an article on how to set this up http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LBX.html

Comment: odd that this is (still) closed as it seems pretty clear what the op is asking at this point, in essence - how do I forward X over a USB-TTY cable from my RPI to my pc (or is this even possible)? @john-la-rooy's answer is a good first approximation, but it could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the X11 forwarding you are referring to, is that done by ssh.

Once you get IP working (probably via PPP) as asked in your [other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/9533/590), you can simply ssh to the RPi and use it's X11 forwarding.

Comment: Thanks! I will most definitely look into this and see if I can get this running. I tried [this](http://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) tutorial, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm going to try again, but I will also try this. Thanks!