# Internet Access over USB to TTL Console Cable

Tags: terminal, serial-console

I have a USB to TTL Console Cable that came in my Raspberry Pi Starter kit and I was wondering if it would be possible to access the internet through it?

I'm guessing it would be *much* slower than an actual internet connection, as it has to first go through my computer then through the Console Cable, but I just think it would be interesting to know (creating a RPi laptop with barebones, TTY only OS that automatically connects over serial - personal idea I thought would be fun to try and get to work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) over the serial line.

To do that you would first need a PPP server on the other computer and make sure the Raspberry Pi is not using the serial port for the console.

Search for Linux PPP tutorials and you probably find what you need to get it working.

Comment: Thanks! I will most definitely look into this and see if I can get this running. I tried [this](http://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) tutorial, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm going to try again, but I will also try this. I hadn't thought of PPP before, but now that you mention it, that would make sense. Thanks!